# Use os.walk to find a folder with specific file extensions under directory tree

Tags: python, filepath, glob, os.walk, directory-tree

I need to traverse all my folders to find the file path of a folder with files with a specific extension (for sake of example, we will say `.txt`). 
I do not know if the folder will be at the top of the tree or at the bottom.

For example, we are starting in:

```
OneDrive/Documents/project/SourceCode
```

The folder containing all the .txt files could be in `OneDrive/Documents/project/SourceCode/TxtFiles` or it could be in `OneDrive/Documents/project/TxtFiles` or it could also be up more past the project file.

How would I find the filepath? I tried using `os.walk`, but I do not have a strong enough understanding of how it works. In the end, I am globbing all of the `.txt` files into a giant list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `pathlib`:

```
from pathlib import Path

base_path = Path('base/path/to/search/from')
text_file = next(base_path.glob('**/*.txt'))
parent_dir = text_file.parent.resolve()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pathlib import Path
from pprint import pprint
import os

def find_files_of_ext(root, ext):
    return [str(Path(dir, file_)) for dir, subdir, files in os.walk(root) for file_ in files if Path(file_).suffix == ext]


filepaths = find_files_of_ext('C:/Users/username/OneDrive', '.jpeg' )
pprint(filepaths)
```